# Can't load project into Visual Studio for Mac Community

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, macos, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio for mac Community and I have a existing website that I've been sent the files for to edit its layout and css a bit locally first and then put live. I want to load it into Visual Studio to begin work but there simply isn't the option to do so?

If it helps here is the file structure of the website/project:

[image: file structure]

Comment: If that structure is from Visual Studio then it appears like it's loaded, as the files are showing.

Comment: That's from sublime ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things for you to know:

- Visual Studio for Mac works only with .NET Core Apps
- .NET Core (no matter the flavor) doesn't support ASP.NET WebForms
- Only .NET Core 2.0 will support VB.NET (I think)

Comment: According to this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes, it supports more than just .NET

Comment: Where is saying that?

Comment: What would be the other non .NET? it says nothing about that.

Comment: So does that mean I can't load this project into Visual Studio for mac?

Comment: @MikeeeGeee no, and I bet that you will never be able to do that unless you migrate that to .net core, but .net does no have support for web forms yet

Comment: @kblok : It looked like it said something about html, iOS audio units, watchOS, etc.; If they are indicating it's .NET only then they should change the wording.

Comment: @l'L'l they mention all that using Xamarin, which we could say it's a .NET Core Flavor

Comment: @kblok: What about `Web Tooling`, is that `.NET`? from what you mention everything listed there ultimately revolves around `.NET` I guess. That's what wasn't clear apparently ( I think that might be where the OP was confused also perhaps ).

Comment: Thanks for all your input. Can I please ask your advise further to this... I have access to a PC now so what version of Visual Studio would be best for me to use to edit this project?

Comment: @MikeeeGeee you could check the web.config file, look for targetFramework and then check this table https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @kblok Thank you! its 4.5 so I need Visual Studio 2012 if I'm not mistaken. Now to get a copy of that!